# How to get Xcode 6 generated XLIFF files to import back into Xcode - renaming is not enough

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode6, xliff

How to export a base development language XLIFF file from Xcode 6 and then re-import it to configure additional localizations. (E.g. export `en.xliff` file and use it to create `fr.xliff` file if you want to add French to an English development language project)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

*I am posting this as an "answer your own question" because I spent hours trying to figure this out and as far as I can tell Apple hasn't documented it.*

The Apple documentation implies it should be sufficient to rename an exported base language XLIFF with a language prefix to be able to import. I.e. if the base localization is English, you should be able to create a file that you can import for French localization just by renaming it from `en.xliff` to `fr.xliff`.

Renaming the file is not enough. You also need to add a `target-language` attribute to every `file` element.

From this:

`<file original="MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext">`

To this:

`<file original="MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="fr">`

Now you can import the file to Xcode and it will create the new localization

Comment: If anyone is using Counterparts as I am, just go to File -> Change XLIFF Translation Locale and change to your selected language.