# Xcode 6 - Base internationalization -exporting and importing en.xliff file

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6, xliff

My app only supports english. I am using base internationalization (English- Development Language)
[image]

**Steps I followed:**
1. Separate out user-facing text using NSLocalizedString();
2. Using Genstrings command i have added Localizable.strings in base.lproj.
3. In Editor >> Export for Localization 
4. Save en.xliff and provide to translator team for updating English content
5. While importing updated en.xliff file, i got below error.
[image]

Might be i doing in wrong way to export/import for English. Please suggest me the best approach for handling English content. (development language).

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious to me what you want to achieve: do you want to have your strings translated into some language other than English, or do you want to run your strings through an English linguistic review? For the first case the error message is pretty clear: check if the `file` element in your translated XLIFF file has a `target-language` attribute and add it if not. Details about this attribute can be found in the XLIFF spec [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#file).

If adding this attribute is not enough you may also want to look at the answer to [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346003/how-to-get-xcode-6-generated-xliff-files-to-import-back-into-xcode-renaming-is?rq=1).

For the second case XLIFF is not really a good format.

Comment: First version of app is supporting English but later version when we add more languages in app, review team will add target-language attribute as you mentioned. Question is about second case where i want to give all my strings to English linguistic team for review for first version. What's the best way to handle if XLIFF is not good option here.

Comment: XLIFF is a format made for translation, not for single-language review: it contains many features that are relevant during translation, but not during linguistic review (like markup of placeholder tags). I do not know if XCode offers any other string export options than XLIFF: in my opinion your reviewers might be better off with a simple two-column table than with XLIFF. 
From what I have read about XCode's localization approach so far Apple may not have anticipated the need for source language review. You could cheat and abuse some target language you will not need.

Comment: Thanks @Jenszcz Agreed with two-column table approach for single-language review.

Comment: I think the point is can you import the strings for the "Base" language through an xliff - as far as I can see you cannot.